# Send message on model save to anyone at WebSocket URL using Channels 2.0

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm trying to send a message to all users with an open websocket connection at a specific URL each time a model is saved. I'm using the Channels community project [knocker](https://github.com/nephila/django-knocker) as a reference but in doing so I have to modify it to work with Channels 2.0.

Using signals fired on a model's `post_save` knocker sends a notification to the Group.

In Channels 2.0, Groups are handled differently so this line `Group('myGroup').send({'text': json.dumps(knock)})` in the [`send_knock`](https://github.com/nephila/django-knocker/blob/master/knocker/mixins.py) method isn't working. Is it possible to modify this line to work with the consumer below?

```
class WeightConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.group_name = 'weight'

        # Join group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to make use of `get_channel_layer()`

```
def send_knock(self, created=False):
    """
    Send the knock in the associated channels Group
    """
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    group_name = 'weight'
    weight = '%s' % self.get_knocker_weight()
    # Send message to group
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        group_name,
        {
            'type': 'weight_message',
            'weight': weight
        }
    )
```

Then add another method to the consumer.

```
class WeightConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    ...

    def receive(self, text_data):
        pass

    def weight_message(self, event):
        weight = event['weight']

        # Send message to websocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'weight': weight
        }))
```